# Train_test_split gridsearch and cross validation

Tags: python, cross-validation, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, train-test-split

I'm trying to do sentiment analysis on text docoments but I got lost in the steps.
So my goal is to:

1. Train SVM, KNN and Naive Bayes algorithms
2. Use gridsearch to find best parameters
3. Evaluate models accuracy and find the best one
4. Use those parameters and get optimal result

Almost on every guide I find that train_test_split method is used. But I've read that Holdout cross validation method isn't very accurate. It's when you split data into train test sets for example 80:20 and hold that 20% for the testing. So instead i wanted to use K-folds cross validation. But the question is how could i use it and do i still need to split my data into train test sets?

So far what i've tried is:

```
    sentences = svietimas_data['text']
    y = svietimas_data['sentiment']
    
    sentences_train, sentences_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sentences, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
    sentences_train, sentences_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(sentences_train, y_train, test_size=0.1111, random_state=1)
    
    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
    weights = ['uniform', 'distance']
    metric = ['euclidean', 'manhattan', 'minkowski']
    k_range = list(range(1, 31))
    param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=k_range, weights = weights, metric = metric )
    
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False, max_df=100)
    vectorizer.fit(sentences_train)
    
    X_train = vectorizer.transform(sentences_train)
    X_validate = vectorizer.transform(sentences_validate)
    X_test = vectorizer.transform(sentences_test)
    
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid, cv=10,scoring='accuracy', return_train_score=False)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    print(grid_search.best_score_)
    print(grid_search.best_params_)
```

I split the data into train validate and test - 80:10:10. I use my train data for the gridsearch parameter analysis to find best parameters and after that i put those parameters into my classifier to use it with validate and test sets to find the best results like this:

```
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred_validate = classifier.predict(X_validate)
    print(classification_report(y_validate, y_pred_validate))
    
    y_pred_test = classifier.predict(X_test)
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_test))
```

But since this method isn't very accurate could i instead use my whole data set on gridsearch and thats it? or after getting best parameters with 80% data set I should put those parameters into classifier and use K-folds cross validation with full data set? Because using gridsearch or k-folds with train (80%) data i waste 20% of the data and as far as i know if i would use 100% of the data K-folds would split that data into for example gievn k-5 sets and the data wouldn't count as seen or overfitted?
Or what my exact steps should be to correctly achieve that goal?

Comment: Fyi SO is for programming questions, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing parameter tuning, which is equivalent to training: this is why you must keep a fresh test set to evaluate the final model (otherwise performance could be overestimated).

However since you're using CV in the first level of training, you need only one more test set. So the typical process would be like this:

- Split training and test set
- Apply CV to the training set for all combinations of parameters (grid search), then pick the best parameters.
- Re-train the final model on the full training set with the best parameters.
- Evaluate the model on the test set

> But since this method isn't very accurate could i instead use my whole data set on gridsearch and thats it?

If you don't evaluate on a fresh test set after parameter tuning, you might have overfitting (best parameters by chance) and you wouldn't know it, the performance would be biased.

> or after getting best parameters with 80% data set I should put those parameters into classifier and use K-folds cross validation with full data set?

It is possible to use CV also for the last stage of evaluation, but it's not so simple: you would have to used nested CV, it's not really worth it and it would take a lot more time because you would have to repeat the parameter tuning stage for each training inside the top-level CV.

> Because using gridsearch or k-folds with train (80%) data i waste 20% of the data

Actually you don't waste the data. The test set is needed only for the purpose of reliable evaluation, but once this is done you could perfectly re-train your model on the full data.

Also this is a bad sign when 20% of the data matters a lot for performance, it means that the model probably doesn't have a large enough training set and even the full data might not be enough.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's much more clear for me!